# Having trouble getting clion to build symbols on my project in Linux

Tags: clion

I've set my clion64.vmoptions -Xmx8000m (increased from 2000, and then from 4000) but it always craps out on the Building Symbols step. It's a large project (13,000+ files), but surely others have had larger ones? Is there another magic setting I can change?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue. I believe that in my case the problem isn't in allocated memory because I'm open HelloWorld project. I found the following solution, maybe in your case, it's also will be work.

So, decision:

I removed all path to the environment in the settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> ToolChains.

I'm open my project and return environment path(minigw in my case).

After that, CLion isn't crapped out on the Building Symbols step